# Selenium IDE: If variable contains some text

Tags: selenium-ide

In the Selenium IDE Firefox add-on I'm trying to create an If statement that will execute a one way if my variable contains a certain text and will execute another way if it contains other text. The issue I'm having is I need it to check just one or two words in a long text so I can't use ==. What I've been trying to do is:

Command     | Target                   | Value

Store Value | id = stuff               | Test

If          | ${Test}.contains('text') |

But this hasn't been working. Any help with this is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use this contraction for such cases.

```
Command | Target | Value
Store Value | id = stuff | Test
execute script | var t = ${Test}; return t.includes('text'); | tmp
If | ${tmp}=='true' |
```

Comment: That worked except I had to use includes instead of contains. Thank you!

Comment: i concur with @Aaron . I have attempted to edit the answer (not sure if this is the correct thing to do!)